# If condition is "None" the loop starts somewhere else than I want

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I try to code my first little text based role play game.

The first step would be to enter your character name and then type "y" if you are fine with the name and "n" if you want to change the name.

So I want that the Program is asking you again to enter "y" or "n" if you fatfinger a "g" for example. And only let you reenter your name if you type "n"
Instead of these the program will let you reenter your name directly if you enter "g".

I already tried to do a "while True or False" loop around the _yesorno function.

Here is the code:
main.py

```
from Classes.character import character
from functions.yesorno import _yesorno
#character
char = character()
while True:
  print("please enter a name for your character")
  char.set_name(input())
  print("Your name is: " + char.name + ". Are you happy with your choice? Type 'y' for yes, 'n' for no.")
  if _yesorno(input()):
    break
  else:
    continue
```

_yesorno.py

```
def _yesorno(input:str)->bool:
    if input == "y":
      return True
    elif input == "n":
      return False
    else:
      print("please use y for yes and n for no")
      return None
```

As I am pretty new I would be happy, if you can explain your answer newbie friendly and not only with "your logic is wrong" :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds to me like you should have two loops -- an inner one that repeats until either a "y" or "n" is entered, and an outer one that repeats until a "y" is entered.  The prompt to enter a name would then go inside the outer loop, but not inside the inner loop.

Comment: Hi @jason44107 thanks for your response. So you mean in the _yesorno.py function ? first while true loop checks if the input is y or  n and the second loops dircects back to the y or n question ?

Comment: There are a number of ways you could do this.  If I were developing this, I think I'd make a function to ask the user about the name.  It takes the character name as input and returns a bool.  It asks the user if they're happy with their choice of name and loops until the user enters either a "y" or "n".  Then I'd call that function from inside the loop of the main code.  In this arrangement, the main code's loop is the outer loop, and the loop in the function is the inner loop.

Comment: Okay, again thanks @jason44107 I will try it out tonight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this with a pair of recursive functions. One that ran until the user gave a valid response, the other until a name was properly set.

Note that in many cases, recursive functions can be rewritten as loops and since python lacks tail call optimization, some people will prefer not using recursion. I think it is usually fine to do so though.

```
def get_input_restricted(prompt, allowed_responses):
    choice = input(prompt)
    if choice in allowed_responses:
        return choice

    print(f"\"{choice}\" must be one of {allowed_responses}")
    return get_input_restricted(prompt, allowed_responses)

def set_character_name():
    prospective_name = input("Enter a name for your character: ")
    print(f"Your name will be: {prospective_name}.")

    confirmation = get_input_restricted("Are you happy with your choice (y|n)? ", ["y", "n"])
    if "y" == confirmation:
        return prospective_name

    return set_character_name()

character_name = set_character_name()
print(f"I am your character. Call me {character_name}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

`if None` is equal to while `if False`. Python have dynamic typing for types.

To check wrong input you can do things like:

```
def _yesorno(input_:str)->bool:
    while input_ not in ['y', 'n']:
        print("please use y for yes and n for no")
        input_ = input()
    return input_ == 'y'
```

That code check input directly instead itself. `input_ not in ['y', 'n']` that part check if your `input_` is one of array element.

After user enter 'y' or 'n' the function return proper result.

Comment: Hi thanks for your elegant solution! I don't understand it completely to be honest. the while loop will be repeated until the input = y or input = n I get that. But out of the loop you return y for input_ shouldn't it be True if input = yes and False if input is n ?

Comment: @e.nice It's not returning `y`. It's returning `input_ == 'y'` which evaluates to `True` if `input_ == 'y'` and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why an input of 'g' is making the user reenter their name is because 'None' is treated as False therefore the loop will continue... you could try a simple if statement in a while loop and disregard your _yesorno function with

```
while(True):
     print("please enter a name for your character")
     charName = input()
     while(True):
         print("Your name is: " + charName + ". Are you happy with your choice? Type 'y' for yes, 'n' for no.")
         yesorno = input()
         if(yesorno == 'y' or yesorno == 'n'):
             break
     if(yesorno == 'y'):
         break
char.set_name(charName)
print("and your name is {0}".format(char.name))
```